# how to query entity from RegardingObjectID?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

We can query the web api endpoint like so:

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=name&$top=3 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
```

**When the response contains the regardingobjectid field, how do we issue a similar call against that record?**

```
{
 "@odata.context": "[Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#accounts(name)",
 "value": [
  {
   "@odata.etag": "W/\"501097\"",
   "name": "Fourth Coffee (sample)",
   "accountid": "89390c24-9c72-e511-80d4-00155d2a68d1",
   "regardingobjectid":"dfdc331f-1cff-4bce-acd7-4815b2e87a30"
  },
 ]
}
```

**Is there an odata way to query for regardingobjectid, such as:**

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/Entity?regardingobjectid eq 'dfdc331f-1cff-4bce-acd7-4815b2e87a30'
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work if we want to filter with related record.

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=name&$filter=_regardingobjectid_value eq guid
```

**Note**: guid without single quotes

To query column values from related entity (single record), use `expand`. For example - to get primary contact details in Account record:

```
?$select=name&$expand=primarycontactid($select=fullname,jobtitle,annualincome)
```

I would recommend [CRM REST Builder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) for building queries.

Ref: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mscrmcustomization/archive/2016/10/18/ms-crm-2016-web-api-operations-retrieve-single-or-multiple-records

Comment: I'm sorry perhaps I need to update my question. I'd like to know if it's possible to query the linked record? For example if the regardingobjectid is referencing an opportunity record then I want to be able to query that opportunity record.

Comment: Yes you can using expand

Comment: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/joegilldynamicscrm/archive/2016/03/23/web-api-querying-with-expand

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to retrieve the regarding object id value

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.1/emails(B8345099-6074-E711-810F-00155D6FD705)?$select=_regardingobjectid_value", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
            var _regardingobjectid_value = result["_regardingobjectid_value"];
            var _regardingobjectid_value_formatted = result["_regardingobjectid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
            var _regardingobjectid_value_lookuplogicalname = result["_regardingobjectid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"];
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

*Please note the header to include odata annotations.

Which should return this:

```
{
"@odata.context": "http://xxxx/api/data/v8.1/$metadata#emails(_regardingobjectid_value)/$entity",
"@odata.etag": "W/\"633069\"",
"_regardingobjectid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.associatednavigationproperty": "regardingobjectid_account_email",
"_regardingobjectid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname": "account",
"_regardingobjectid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Coho Winery (sample)",
"_regardingobjectid_value": "b3cc84f2-be0d-e711-8104-00155d6fd705",
"activityid": "b8345099-6074-e711-810f-00155d6fd705"
}
```

`_regardingobjectid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname` gives us the entity name and
`_regardingobjectid_value` gives us the id we need to query the regarding record:

```
/api/data/v8.1/accounts(b3cc84f2-be0d-e711-8104-00155d6fd705)
```